# Is the Lum 2022 Remake trailer first scene a direct reference to Lum: The Forever final scene?

Tags: urusei-yatsura

Lum the Forever is often regarded as the weirdest movie in the Urusei Yatsura franchise. With multiple overlapping layers of possible interpretations the movie almost feel like a polar opposite to Beautiful Dreamer: the later one is about unmoving eternity while the former carries a message that things have to change.

The final scene of the movie is quite emblematic. A tv screen flickering with some static noise before finally shutting down.

[image]

It is a know fact that Lum the Forever was intended to be the final movie in the series, and based on multiple sources and interviews the movie director Kazuo Yamazaki wanted to send a specific message "I wanted to tell them that they should not focus their entire lives on the series but that they should move out".

It would be too long to explain everything in the movie, so if you are interested just refer to [this site](https://www.furinkan.com/features/articles/rudiakgould.html). The important thing here is that the TV screen at the end of Lum The Forever carried a precise meaning: "the show ended, please forget us and go forward on your life".

Years later...
The remake came.
And the trailer started with a very specific image.

[image]

Another TV screen, coming to life to show a picture of Ataru face.
This seems.. quite deliberate.

So, the question is simple: is there any actual "Word of God" evidence that the scene was specifically made as a counterpart to Lum: the Forever ending?